# Is it possible to import wildcard path in React Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import, react-typescript

I want to import dynamically React Typescript Component from **wildcard path** like below:-

```
const Component = loadable(
  () => import(`../../../src/**/*/${component_name}`),
);
```

Is it possible to import like above using a wildcard?

Lots of solutions found in Stackoverflow but nothing match with the requirement.

Any help will highly appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use React.lazy and Webpack require

```
import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst'
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase'

// registry for components
const components = {}

// Create component
const makeComponent = (path) => React.lazy(() => import(`${path}`));


// Get paths (Webpack)
const requireComponent = require.context(
  '../../../components', // components folder
  true, // look subfolders
  /\w+\.([jt]sx)$/ //regex for files
)

requireComponent.keys().forEach(filePath => {
  // Get component config
  const Component = makeComponent(filePath);

  // Get PascalCase name of component
  const componentName = upperFirst(
    camelCase(
    // Gets the file name regardless of folder depth
     filePath
      .split('/')
      .pop()
      .replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
   );

  components[componentName] = Component;
)
```

This solution may require restart Webpack after each new component that you add to
components folder.
Component names (aka fileNames in our case) should be uniq.
React.lazy required default export

Solution based on:

1. https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html
2. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: Thanks for your solution. You are awesome.

Comment: In the above code `makeComponent` isn't used. I believe it should be used inside requireComponent block. *update*: edited code in post.